# How to center images inside navigation bar (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im trying to figure out how to make my navigation bar images be centered on each device. Currently they are all a little off center and when I try to use spacers, it'll fix one device but throw of every other device.

```
NavigationLink(destination: TableView(), isActive: self.$toTable) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            ZStack {
                                Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rectangle 548"))
                                Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_1")).renderingMode(.original).offset(x:-35)
                                Text("Jake").font(.custom("Poppins-Light", size:16)).foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.79, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0))
                            }
                            ZStack {
                                Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rectangle 548"))
                                Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "money 1")).renderingMode(.original).offset(x:-35)
                                Text("175.84").font(.custom("Poppins-Light", size:16)).foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.79, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0)).offset(x:5)
                            }
                            ZStack {
                                Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rectangle 548"))
                                Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "poker-chip 1")).renderingMode(.original).offset(x:-35)
                                Text("1").font(.custom("Poppins-Light", size:16)).foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.79, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0))
                            }
                        }
                        
                })
```

[The top three bars is where I am having my issues centering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiD2a.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add `Spacer` at both ends. Here's how:

```
HStack {
    Spacer()
    ZStack {
        Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rectangle 548"))
        Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_1")).renderingMode(.original).offset(x:-35)
        Text("Jake").font(.custom("Poppins-Light", size:16)).foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.79, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0))
    }
    ZStack {
        Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rectangle 548"))
        Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "money 1")).renderingMode(.original).offset(x:-35)
        Text("175.84").font(.custom("Poppins-Light", size:16)).foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.79, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0)).offset(x:5)
    }
    ZStack {
        Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rectangle 548"))
        Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "poker-chip 1")).renderingMode(.original).offset(x:-35)
        Text("1").font(.custom("Poppins-Light", size:16)).foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.79, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0, opacity: 1.0))
    }
    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: This worked party, they are all exactly the same now but more to the right. I will try padding to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Use `.frame` modifier to get exactly what you're going for.